# Unable to call method on object created from class

Tags: javascript, methods

I have built a class and created an object from it. However, when viewing in the console I am unable to call the method changeColor on the object as it is 'not defined' but I appear to be looking right at it... What am I missing please?

This is my class constructor script called car.js:

```js
class NewCar {
    constructor (
        make,
        model,
        year,
        seats,
        color,
        price,
        hybrid,
    )
    {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
        this.seats = seats;
        this.color = color;
        this.price = price;
        this.hybrid = hybrid;
    };

    changeColor (newColor) {
        this.color = newColor;
    }
}


export default NewCar;
```

Here is the script that imports and uses the constructor to build a volvoxc40 object from it, called script.js.

```js
import NewCar from "./car.js"

const volvoxc40 = new NewCar(
    "Volvo",
    "xc 40",
    2022,
    5,
    "red",
    20000,
    true,
);

console.log ('The new car: ', volvoxc40
);
```

And for completeness, here is the HTML which references the 2 scripts:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Classes</title>
    <script type="module" src="car.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you are entering into the console?

Comment: I just tried out the code above and `volvoxc40.changeColor` is a function, and works when called.

Comment: Where in the module code are you calling `changeColor`?

Comment: Yes, module-scoped variables are not in scope on the console. Place a breakpoint instead

Comment: Could you expand on breakpoints please?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/